# Java StopWatch in ChessGame

Tags: java, multithreading

I have two threads in my ChessGame and I want to implement time control:

1. Turn of first player: second_thread.stop(), first_thread.run();
2. counterOfSteps++;
3. Turn of second player: first_thread.stop(), second_thread.run();
4. counterOfSteps++;

I have founded many information about `Timer` but I need Threads.
Second thread the same.

There is my code of first thread and it doesn't work because time isn't stopped (System.currentTimeMillis)

```
first = new Thread() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        final long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
        final long duration = 10800000; //3 hours
        while (true) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(100);
                if (counterOfSteps % 2 == 0) {
                    System.out.println("Time" + ((duration - (System.currentTimeMillis() - time)) / 1000) % 60);
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                LOG.log(Level.SEVERE, "Unexpected interrupt", ex);
            }
        }
    }
};
```

How to solve this problem?

*Update:*

I don't use .stop().  I wrote is for example how to realize.

Comment: Don't use `Thread.stop()`.

Comment: @bcsb1001 I create first and second thread in separate method. And I wanna make a pause in thread, and run another.  I realized this with stepOfCounter, but System.currentTimeMillis still running and pause doesn't work.

Comment: @GlacialMan Yes. this countdown timer writes in GUI label

Comment: @GlacialMan swing :)

Comment: why you don't use timer from swing

Answer (score 0):

> I have founded many information about Timer but I need Threads.

No.  If all you are trying to do is implement a chess clock, then you don't need threads for that.  A `Timer` task that wakes up every second (or every 1/10 second) can;

- look at whose turn it is (e.g., `counterOfSteps % 2`),
- compute how much time that player has used, and
- Update the appropriate text box in the GUI.

To compute how much time, it'll need to know three things;

- What time it is now (e.g., `System.currentTimeMillis()`),
- What time it *was* when the current turn started, and
- How much time the player already had on the clock when the current turn started.

There is no way to pause the system clock (i.e., `System.currentTimeMillis()`), but that's not a problem.  If you sample the clock at the start of each turn, then you can compute the duration of the current turn as `System.currentTimeMillis()` minus the start time.

Answer (score 0):

I used this example for my quiz, i have 10sec do answer on question this timer decrease `int t` every 1sec, and set how many times left in some `JLabel`. You can make 2 object of Timer, first object for first player and second object for second player. You can stop timer when someone finish the move and start second timer...

```
int t=10
lb2=new JLabel(t);
tim=new Timer(1000,new ActionListener(){
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        if(t>0){
        t--;
        lb2.setText(String.valueOf(t));
        }else{
            tim.stop();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Time is up");
            }
        }
    });
}
```